# Service object not getting initialised/ not calling onServiceCreated

Tags: android, service

I'm making a music player app. When I click list item in SongsFragment.java it sends intent to PlayerActivity.java with the song position. The musicSrv is null always. I looked for Activity lifecyle on google and figured out it has something to do with this. Since I'm beginner so couldn't apply that.

SongsFragment:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //musicSrv.setSong(position);
    //musicSrv.playSong();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), PlayerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("pos", position);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In PlayerActivity.java:

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private MusicService musicSrv;
private Intent playIntent;
private boolean musicBound=false;
private static final String POS = "pos";
private int passedPos;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    passedPos = extras.getInt("pos",0);
    musicSrv.setSong(passedPos);
    musicSrv.playSong();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
}


ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MusicService.MusicBinder binder = (MusicService.MusicBinder)service;
        //Get service
        musicSrv = binder.getService();
        //Pass list
        ArrayList<Song> songs = ((DataFetcher)getApplicationContext()).songList;
        musicSrv.setList(songs);
        musicBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        musicBound = false;
    }
};

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(playIntent==null) {
        playIntent = new Intent(this,(Class)MusicService.class);
        bindService(playIntent,musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(playIntent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopService(playIntent);
    musicSrv=null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Error: I get "`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void services.MusicService.setSong(int)' on a null object reference`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `onCreate()` is called before `onStart()`. `musicSrv` will be `null`, because you have not called `bindService()` yet.

Second, `bindService()` itself is asynchronous. It will be some time later before your `onServiceConnected()` method is called.

You cannot use `musicSrv` until you assign that field a value, and you cannot do that until inside of `onServiceConnected()` at the earliest.

So, move your calls related to `musicSrv` into `onServiceConnected()` or some later event, after you know that `musicSrv` should be ready.

Also, do not call `bindService()` directly, as that will get you in trouble with configuration changes with this activity. Call `bindService()` (and, later, `unbindService()`) using the `Application` object (e.g., `getApplicationContext().bindService()`).

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I moved musicSrv related statements to onServiceConnected() now songs are being played.